# jq recursively update values for certain elements

Tags: json, recursion, edit, jq

The intent for the JSON data below is to update the value of the field `dst` with the value of `src` within all elements of `type` `t`, regardless of depth within the tree, while at the same time preserving the whole structure of the data.

Is this possible with `jq`? My several attempts have boiled down to the following command that is not working to achieve the intended purpose:

`$ jq -r 'map_values(select(.. | .type? == "t" |= (.dst = .src)))'`

```
{
    "a": "b",
    "c": [
        {
            "type": "t",
            "src": "xx",
            "dst": "zz"
        },
        {
            "type": "t",
            "src": "xx",
            "dst": "zz"
        }
    ],
    "d": [
        {
            "e": [
                {
                    "type": "t",
                    "src": "xx",
                    "dst": "zz"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "t2",
            "src": "xx",
            "dst": "zz"
        }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible with jq?

jq is Turing-complete :-)

Here's a simple solution:

```
walk( if type == "object" and .type == "t" then .dst = .src else . end)
```

If your jq does not have `walk/1`, then it might be a good time to upgrade (to jq 1.6); otherwise, you can snarf its def from the web, e.g. by googling: `jq "def walk"`

### Alternatively ...

```
reduce paths as $x (.;
    if (getpath($x)|.type? // false) == "t"
    then setpath( $x + ["dst"]; getpath( $x + ["src"] ))
    else . end)
```